# Radionomy get title and artist name

Tags: xml

When I query radionomy url like for example:

```
https://api.radionomy.com/currentsong.cfm?radiouid=" + radiouid + "&apikey=" + apikey + "&callmeback=yes&type=xml&cover=yes&previous=yes"
```

I get such response:

```
<tracks>
    <radioname>RTFM</radioname>
    <rank>0</rank>
    <isradionomy>1</isradionomy>
    <radurl>http://www.radionomy.com/rtfm</radurl>
    <track>
        <uniqueid>1967707095</uniqueid>
        <title>120edf46fbf9ead86331f3341856d4a9</title>
        <artists>120edf46fbf9ead86331f3341856d4a9</artists>
        <starttime>2021-12-22 07:39:44.82</starttime>
        <playduration></playduration>
        <current>1</current>
        <cover>http://i3.radionomy.com/tracks/232/?radiouid=8f255562-3f11-406b-8d98-f98cb23c84ec</cover>
        <callmeback>102746</callmeback>

    </track> 
</tracks>
```

How do I get title and artist from this, what are these value representing?

```xml
<title>120edf46fbf9ead86331f3341856d4a9</title>
<artists>120edf46fbf9ead86331f3341856d4a9</artists>
```

Comment: Those values look like IDs, but the fact that they're the same for both the title and artists looks a bit odd. Do you have any documentation for this API?

Comment: I found this:  https://board.radionomy.com/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=74  but in their example full title and artist are displayed.

Comment: Does this happen with other songs too?

Comment: Havent tried, I dont have other songs.